# Can we interpret the number of particles in a state as an amplitude of oscillation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

**TL;DR**

If we have a classical field expressed in a Fourier expansion, is the amplitude of each mode related to the particle number in that specific mode?

**Attempt to formalize**

We know particles should have energy $E_k=\sqrt{k^2+m^2}$ if $n$ particles are in this wave mode then $E_k = n\sqrt{k^2+m^2} = n\omega_k$. We know that spin 0 particles are described by the Klein-Gordon equation and if we consider a particle that has definite momentum we have the solution

$$\phi(k,t) = (2\pi)^3 \delta^3(k-k')A_{k'}e^{-i\omega_kt} + (2\pi)^3 \delta^3(k+k')A_{k'}^*e^{i\omega_kt}$$

Which has in the following form in position space
$$\phi(x,t) = A_{k'}e^{-i\omega_{k'}t+ikx} + A_{k'}^*e^{i\omega_{k'}t+ikx}$$
If we now use Noethers theorem to calculate the energy of the field we can find
$$E_{k'}=\omega^2_{k'}(A_{k'}^* A_{k'}+A_{k'}A_{k'}^*)\int dx$$
$$E_{k'}=\omega^2_{k'}(A_{k'}^* A_{k'}+A_{k'}A_{k'}^*)V$$
If we make the substitution $A_{k'} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\omega_{k'} V}} a_{k'}$
$$E_{k'}=\frac{1}{2}\omega_{k'}(a_{k'}^*a_{k'}+a_{k'}a_{k'}^*)$$
$$E_{k'}=\omega_{k'}a_{k'}^*a_{k'}$$
If $a_{k'} = e^{i\alpha}\sqrt{n}$ then the amplitude of the oscillation would result in $n$ particles having that moment.  If we generalize this to $\phi$ occupying many arbitrary momenta states we get that.
$$E = \sum_{k'} \omega_{k'} a_{k'}^*a_{k'}$$
$$\phi(x,t) = \sum_{k'}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\omega_{k'} V}}\left[a_{k'}e^{-i\omega_{k'}t+ikx} + a_{k'}^*e^{i\omega_{k'}t+ikx}\right]$$
$$\phi(k,t) = (2\pi)^3\sum_{k'}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\omega_{k'} V}}\left[ \delta^3(k-k')a_{k'}e^{-i\omega_{k'}t} + \delta^3(k+k') a_{k'}^*e^{i\omega_{k'}t}\right]$$
A natural way to encode the state of a field configuration is using a fock space. For example $|2_{k_1},1_{k_2}\rangle$ would correspond to the field configouration

$$\phi(k,t) = (2\pi)^3\sqrt{\frac{2}{2\omega_{k_1} V}}\left[ \delta^3(k-k_1)e^{i\alpha_{k_1}}e^{-i\omega_{k_1}t} + \delta^3(k+k_1) e^{-i\alpha_{k_1}}e^{i\omega_{k_1}t}\right]+ (2\pi)^3\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\omega_{k_1} V}}\left[ \delta^3(k-k_2)e^{i\alpha_{k_2}}e^{-i\omega_{k_2}t} + \delta^3(k+k_2) e^{-i\alpha_{k_2}}e^{i\omega_{k_2}t}\right]$$

Where $\alpha_{k_1},\alpha_{k_2}$ are unknown phases. If we want the field to occupy multiple configourations we can write this as $|\phi\rangle=|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3}, \cdots\rangle + |n_{k'_1},n_{k'_2},n_{k'_3}, \cdots\rangle + \cdots$. If we promote the fields to operators we can see that
$$\hat\phi(k,t) = (2\pi)^3\sum_{k'}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\omega_{k'} V}}\left[ \delta^3(k-k')\hat a_{k'}e^{-i\omega_{k'}t} + \delta^3(k+k') \hat a_{k'}^\dagger e^{i\omega_{k'}t}\right]$$ Where intuitively
$$\hat \phi(k)|\phi\rangle=\hat \phi(k)|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3}, \cdots\rangle + \hat \phi(k)|n_{k'_1},n_{k'_2},n_{k'_3}, \cdots\rangle + \cdots = \phi_1(k)|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3}, \cdots\rangle + \phi_2(k)|n_{k'_1},n_{k'_2},n_{k'_3}, \cdots\rangle + \cdots$$
$$\hat a_{k_2}|\phi\rangle=\hat a_{k_2}|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3}, \cdots\rangle + \hat a_{k_2}|n_{k'_1},n_{k'_2},n_{k'_3}, \cdots\rangle + \cdots = e^{i\alpha_{k_2}}\sqrt{n_{k_2}}|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3}, \cdots\rangle + e^{i\alpha_{k'_2}}\sqrt{n_{k'_2}}|n_{k'_1},n_{k'_2},n_{k'_3}, \cdots\rangle + \cdots$$
$$\hat a^\dagger_{k_2}|\phi\rangle=\hat a_{k_2}^\dagger|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3}, \cdots\rangle + \hat a_{k_2}^\dagger|n_{k'_1},n_{k'_2},n_{k'_3}, \cdots\rangle + \cdots = e^{-i\alpha_{k_2}}\sqrt{n_{k_2}}|n_{k_1},n_{k_2},n_{k_3}, \cdots\rangle + e^{-i\alpha_{k'_2}}\sqrt{n_{k'_2}}|n_{k'_1},n_{k'_2},n_{k'_3}, \cdots\rangle + \cdots$$
My question is: Is this interpretation of quantum field theory correct? If this is a correct way to understand what a quantum field is, then why when quantizing the theory the standard way when you act $\hat\phi$ onto a definite $n$ particle state we get a state that has a superposition of $n-1$ and $n+1$ particles?

Comment: Why would you expect the field strength $\hat\phi$ to commute with the particle number? I suggest you look back to the harmonic oscillator for clues: quantizing a free field gives you "a bunch of harmonic oscillators" (one for each $k$), where field strength is "displacement" and particle number is, well, number.

Comment: @HTNW Because in the classical case, we had $E = h\omega a^* a$ and we know $a^*a = n$ so if we know the amplitude, we know the particle number and because the field is made up from the amplitudes, we also know the field configoration